# How to add a trigger to a spreadsheet onformsubmit programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I would like to know how we can add a trigger that fire `onFormSubmit` but in the code.

I know how to do it this way:
Script -> Edition -> Trigger of the project -> Add New

And then add the trigger base on the spreadsheet `onFormsubmit` to fire the function `timerEvent`.

As you can see in this screenshot:
[image]

But my problem is: how you can create the trigger programmatically?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

```
/* Gobal settings */

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

var RangeSheet = ss.getRangeByName("SheettoSync");
var RangeCalendar = ss.getRangeByName("CalendarID");
var RangeMail = ss.getRangeByName("AlertMail");

var calId = RangeCalendar.getValue();
var alertEmail = RangeMail.getValue();
var sheetName = RangeSheet.getValue();

function setTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('timerEvent')
    .forSpreadsheet(sheetName)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

But this code doesn't work, nothing happens to my spreadsheet. However if I set the trigger through the web interface it works as expected.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: `forSpreadsheet()` accepts spreadsheet id or spreadsheet. `sheetName` probably doesn't contain `id`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
function setTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('timerEvent')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

And then you need to run the function `setTrigger()` once manually.